# How to convert JSON to a key-value dictionary using typescript?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, loops, lodash

I have the following json example:

```
{
    "MyTest:": [{
            "main": {
                "name": "Hello"
            },
            "test2": {
                "test3": {
                    "test4": "World"
                },
                "test5": 5
            }
        },
        {
            "main": {
                "name": "Hola"
            },
            "test6": [{
                    "name": "one"
                },
                {
                    "name": "two"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to convert it to an array of arrays with key-values

```
[[main.name: "Hello",test2.test3.test4: "World", test2.test5: 5] , 
[main.name = "Hola", test6.name: "one", test6.name: "two"] ];
```

Looking for some function like "is leaf" - so I will know that is the value.

Any advise for deep iteration will be very appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `flattenObject()` function returns an object of one level, with the keys built from all sub keys. The recursive function checks if the current value is an object. If it is, it iterates the object with `_.flatMap()` and calls itself on each property with the keys collected so far. If the value is not an object, it returns an object with a single property (the joined keys), and the value.

It then merges the array of { key: value } objects to a single object.

```js
const flattenObject = val => {
  const inner = (val, keys = []) => 
    _.isObject(val) ? // if it's an object or array
      _.flatMap(val, (v, k) => inner(v, [...keys, k])) // iterate it and call fn with the value and the collected keys
      :
      { [keys.join('.')]: val } // return the joined keys with the value
      
  return _.merge({}, ...inner(val))
}

const obj = {"MyTest":[{"main":{"name":"Hello"},"test2":{"test3":{"test4":"World"},"test5":5}},{"main":{"name":"Hola"},"test6":[{"name":"one"},{"name":"two"}]}]}

const result = obj.MyTest.map(flattenObject)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. new with TS. For some reason it shows me an error in [...keys, k] and in merge ...inner(val) saying  that argument of type string[] is not assignable to parameter of type never[] and the second one shows the following :  Type 'any[] | { [x: string]: null | undefined; }' is not an array type or a string type. Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators.ts(2569)

Comment: This is standard JS with lodash. You'll need to handle the typings yourself.